# Keycloak 22.0.3 Error: Could not find or load main class Mobile

Tags: java, keycloak

I'm trying to start the bat file but it always fails with the below error.
I have tried different openJDK version 20,21.. but the error is always the same.

kc.bat start-dev
Error: Could not find or load main class Mobile
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Mobile

Expected result: Start the Keycloak server.

Comment: The duplink is tentative.  You should be able confirm it by looking at the `kc.bat` file installed on your system.

Comment: If it is not that problem, my advice would be to add some debugging to the `kc.bat` file to capture the complete Java command line.  Or (if I am reading the bat file correctly) setting `%PRINT_ENV%` to `true` will print out the final settings for `%JAVA_OPTS%` and `%JAVA_RUN_OPTS%`.

Comment: Hello Stephen,
Thank you for the reply.
I'm not sure what you mean by the "duplink is tentative".

What I found with process explorer is that java.exe is looking for Mobile.class inside the Keycloak bin folder which doesn't exist and I have no idea why. I installed the software on another machine and there this is not happening.

 [Mobile.Class.Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/8XHHPKa.png)

Comment: My hunch is that because you are in a directory called "Scanman Mobile Application" the batch file is passing that string to Java and Java is taking it as three separate words, hence looking for a class called "Mobile". Maybe try installing KeyCloak in a different directory if possible, and see if it fixes it.

Comment: k314159's suggestion is plausible.  You want to use an installation directory name that doesn't have spaces in its name!  But if that isn't the problem, try what I suggested in my second comment.

Comment: Hello, 
k314159 that was it! Renaming the folder did the trick, thank you!
Stepen C, thank you for the help, too!

Comment: Glad you've got it working. I think this is an error in the batch file: it should be wrapping the directory in quotes so that it doesn't split its name using the space characters. You might want to report this bug to the vendor.